# Работа Promise под капотом - два метода resolve?

Tags: javascript, promise

Всем добрый день.

Важная ремарка насчёт моего вопроса: для более детального понимания Промисов я решил воссоздать этот класс своими руками. Тот пример кода, который вы увидите ниже, он максимально, насколько это возможно, примитивный (в реальности он конечно же намного больше и сложнее). Я нарочно сюда не добавил методы reject, then, catch, finally, конструкции try/catch и так далее, чтобы вы полностью сфокусировались конкретно на моём кейсе. Поэтому давайте временно представим, что в нашем случае никаких ошибок вообще не предполагается, есть только всегда успешно работающий код и поэтому есть только метод `resolve()`.

А вопрос у меня как раз по поводу этого метода. Я правильно понимаю, что у класса Promise их два - один статический, другой нет? Почему я спрашиваю, разделен ли этот метод на статический и НЕ статический? Потому что смотрите - когда мы вызываем этот метод следующим образом (не создавая экземпляр с помощью ключевого слова new):

```
const promise = Promise.resolve(1);
console.log(promise);
```

то метод моментально возвращает нам новый зарезолвленный экземпляр Промиса без всякой асинхронности. То есть если бы был только СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ метод resolve, то как бы мы тогда резолвили экземпляры, которые уже создаём сами с помощью ключевого слова `new`? Вот посмотрите:

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 1000);
});
```

То есть в данном случае, если бы был только статический resolve, то созданный экземпляр НЕ зарезолвился бы, потому что этот статический resolve ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ экземпляр Промиса, а не резолвит ТЕКУЩИЙ. Поэтому мне интересно, что судя по всему есть два метода resolve? Второй resolve, который НЕ статический, он резолвит текущий экземпляр, а не возвращает новый. Я правильно понимаю, что так и есть? Либо возможно есть только один метод resolve статический, в котором происходит определённая проверка.

Вот моя реализация Promise:

```
class Promise {
  constructor(executor) {
    // executor - функция-исполнитель, которая передаётся, как параметр - new Promise(executor)
    this.PromiseState = 'pending';
    this.PromiseResult = undefined;
    executor(this.resolve.bind(this));
    // executor принимает в себя два параметра, один из них - метод resolve, поэтому resolve привязывается к экземпляру Promise, созданному в конструкторе, чтобы при вызове зарезолвить этот самый экземпляр
  }
 
  // НЕ статический метод resolve переводит ТЕКУЩИЙ экземпляр Промиса в положительное завершенное состояние
  resolve(value) {
    this.PromiseState = 'fulfilled';
    this.PromiseResult = value;
  }
 
  // СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ метод resolve возвращает НОВЫЙ зарезолвленный экземпляр Промиса
  static resolve(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(value));
  }
}
```

Да, я уже смотрел видео и читал статьи по имплементации Promise, при этом данный вопрос у меня всё таки остался не отвеченным. Разъясните пожалуйста?

Comment: ¿Вы же в курсе, что в javascript нет классов, как нет и статических / нестатических методов, да?

Comment: @user7860670 Не слышал про такое. Как тогда создаются и используются эти классы и статические/нестатические в JS?

Comment: тоже не могу понять, причем там статический/нестатический, если resolve - это аргумент callback?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете реализацию Promise, если он уже как лет 10 реализован https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.js?

Comment: В javascript объектная модель основана на прототипировании, а не на классах. А синтаксические конструкции типа `class Promise` имеют принципиально иной смысл по сравнению с обычными языками с классами, такими как С++ или C#.

Comment: Кстати говоря, есть отличный талмуд по этому вопросу https://learn.javascript.ru/ . Книга очень хорошая, последовательная, текст дополняется современными изменениями и комментариями. Рекомендую прочитать полностью. Также стоит прочитать статью [JavaScript гарден](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/ru/). Там есть ответы на многие вопросы, которые возникнут потом, уже на этапе получения опыта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически, `Promise.resolve` является сахаром для

```
new Promise(function(resolve){
  resolve(x);
});
```

Технически, да - это [статичный](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#using_the_static_promise.resolve_method) метод, так как позволяет вызвать его без `new`.

`function(resolve)` же вызывает колбек, который уже является реализацией [PromiseResolve](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-resolve) функции

Надеюсь, предоставленных ссылок вам хватит, что бы дальше разобраться.

Answer (score -1):

В общем, отвечаю.
Да, примерно так оно и есть. Пока без конкретных доказательств, с другой стороны функционал это доказывает сам.
В официальной [документации](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-promise-objects) упоминания об этом не нашел. Хотя возможно что-то пропустил, трудное чтиво.
В самом объект промиса, если вывести через

```
console.dir(Promise);
```

тоже трудно сказать, при этом в обоих прототипах отсутствует `resolve`.
Поэтому да, если копать в глубь, то примерно так оно и есть. А уж точный ответ знают только разработчики языка.

Comment: _В общем, отвечаю. Да, примерно так оно и есть._ - так - это как? В документации по твоей ссылке даже приведен псевдокод, как именно все работает

Comment: @Grundy Подскажи пожалуйста, в каком именно месте? Возможно реально пропустил.

Comment: [Promise ( executor )](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-promise-executor)